# Entity Framework core does not work when using masstransit library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, masstransit, ef-core-8.0

I have a project, previously ef commands such as add-migration and update-database were working correctly.
But I did some things after which these commands don't work anymore.

1- Adding Resharper plugin. that even by disabling this plugin, these commands still don't work. In addition, I made a test project that with this plugin, those commands worked correctly.

2- Create a new C# library. I created a folder and built the library, but instead of being built in the folder, the library was built in the root. I deleted the folder and the library and there is no trace of this library in the sln file.

3- Update all ef libraries from version 8.0.2 to 8.0.3

In my solution, there are several C# libraries, each of which has its own DbContext (cqrs). In the main project related to Command, there is a DbContext named ContentCommandDbContext, in version 8.0.2, I created another DbContext named ContentCommandDbContextFactory, which inherits from IDesignTimeDbContextFactory and fixes errors.

The problem I have now is that every ef command that I execute in the PackageManagerConsule window does not happen after the build of the project and the program remains running in the background and does not create a script. And it remains running in the background until I restart the computer.

But when I execute commands through CLI, it is done correctly.

Does anyone know where the problem is and how can I fix it so that I can use vs 2022 as before?[image]

-----------Update-----------

I found the problem. The problem is with the ***IPublishEndpoint***
in my custom Interceptor. When I remove the parts related to IPublishEndpoint, the commands work correctly.

Even when I create the database with CLI commands, when the program wants to save data through ef core8, the program still does not work.

```
 public class DomainEventsDispatcherInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;
    //todo using masstransit here
    public DomainEventsDispatcherInterceptor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _publishEndpoint = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPublishEndpoint>();
        _mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
    }

    public override async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var affectedRows = await base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);

        if (affectedRows > 0)
        {
            var aggregateRoots =
                    eventData.Context?.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(current => current.Entity is IAggregateRoot)
                        .Select(current => current.Entity as IAggregateRoot)
                        .ToList()
                ;

            foreach (var aggregateRoot in aggregateRoots)
            {
                // Dispatch Events!
                if (aggregateRoot != null)
                {
                    foreach (var domainEvent in aggregateRoot.DomainEvents)
                    {
                        //  await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent, cancellationToken);
                        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(domainEvent, cancellationToken); //albate domain event ehtenmalan moshkel darad bayad dar eventbus.message bashad baraye namespace ha ke dar masstransit mohem hastand
                                                                                        //add masstransit
                    }

                    // Clear Events!
                    aggregateRoot.ClearDomainEvents();
                }
            }
        }
        return affectedRows;
    }

    public override int SavedChanges(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result)
    {
        var affectedRows = base.SavedChanges(eventData, result);
        if (affectedRows > 0)
        {
            var aggregateRoots =
                    eventData.Context?.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(current => current.Entity is IAggregateRoot)
                        .Select(current => current.Entity as IAggregateRoot)
                        .ToList()
                ;

            foreach (var aggregateRoot in aggregateRoots)
            {
                // Dispatch Events!
                if (aggregateRoot != null)
                {
                    foreach (var domainEvent in aggregateRoot.DomainEvents)
                    {
                        //_mediator.Publish(domainEvent);
                        _publishEndpoint.Publish(domainEvent); //albate domain event ehtenmalan moshkel darad bayad dar eventbus.message bashad baraye namespace ha ke dar masstransit mohem hastand
                    }

                    // Clear Events!
                    aggregateRoot.ClearDomainEvents();
                }
            }
        }
        return affectedRows;
    }
```

And the following code is the settings in the ***Program.cs*** file:

```
...
//add command dbcontext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContentCommandDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(cnn, option =>
    {
        option.EnableRetryOnFailure(6);
        option.MinBatchSize(1);
    });
    options.AddInterceptors(new IInterceptor[]
    {
        new DomainEventsDispatcherInterceptor(serviceProvider)
    }); ;
});
//add query dbcontext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContentQueryDbContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(cnn));
....

builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<ContentCommandDbContext>(o =>
    {
        o.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        o.UseSqlServer();
        o.UseBusOutbox();
    });
    //The outbox can also be added to all consumers using a configure endpoints callback:
    // https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/middleware/outbox
    x.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context, name, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseEntityFrameworkOutbox<ContentCommandDbContext>(context);
    });

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672 ");
        cfg.AutoStart = true;
        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue-name", c => c.ConfigureConsumers(context));
    });
    x.AddConsumers(typeof(CommentAddedEvent).Assembly, typeof(CommentAddedEventHandler).Assembly);
});
...
```

Can someone guide me, where is the problem?

Comment: .NET Core in general doesn't use the Package Manager console. All tooling is called from the command line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But through it, it executes the command line in the background

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not true, the Package Manager console can be perfectly used with .NET Core, e.g. `Install-Package` or `Remove-Package`

Comment: @Lennart tried that in Mac or Linux? The actual EF tools come as .NET Global tools. PMC is only for VS and doesn't really offer any additional features. In both cases though, the packages/tools need to match the EF Core version.